# How to change font size of child QLabel widget from the groupBox

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qlabel

How can use different font & size for the child Widgets in the GroupBox and the tittle for the GroupBox in python

```
def panel(self):
    groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox("voltage Monitor")
    groupBox.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 13))       # the title size is good
    ..

    self.Voltage_Label = []
    ..

    vbox = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.Voltage_Label.append(QtGui.QLabel("voltage1 ")) # i need to have diff Font & size for these 
    self.Voltage_Label.append(QtGui.QLabel("voltage2 "))   
    self.Voltage_Label.append(QtGui.QLabel("voltage3 ")) 
    ..
    vbox.addWidget(self.Voltage_Label[i], i, 0)  
    ..
    groupBox.setLayout(vbox)
    return groupBox
```

I tired this

```
   self.Voltage_Label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
```

I get this error

```
    !! self.Voltage_Label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'setFont' !!
```

but for something like this`title1 = QtGui.QLabel("Sample Title")` as a child widget i can change it by

```
 title1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I was waiting for an answer I wanted to give it a try and found this method/solution for my question:

```
self.Voltage_Label = []

self.Voltage_Label.append(QtGui.QLabel("voltage1 ")) # i need to have diff Font & size for these 
self.Voltage_Label.append(QtGui.QLabel("voltage2 "))   
self.Voltage_Label.append(QtGui.QLabel("voltage3 "))
.
.

for i in xrange(5):
        newfont = QtGui.QFont("Times", 8, QtGui.QFont.Bold) 
        self.Voltage_Label[i].setFont(newfont)
```

Comment: this doesn't change the fonts while ui setup already rendered

Answer (score 5):

You were trying to invoke the method `setFont()` of an object of the class `list` (which hasn't this method), not of the `QtGui.QLabel` object.

You can use a list comprehension for a better scalability and performance:

```
voltages = ["voltage1 ", "voltage2 ", "voltage3 "]

# Populates the list with QLabel objects
self.Voltage_Label = [QtGui.QLabel(x) for x in voltages]

# Invokes setFont() for each object
[x.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 8, QtGui.QFont.Bold)) for x in self.Voltage_Label]
```

If you need more voltage labels you only have to modify the list `voltages`.

And then even:

```
[vbox.addWidget(self.Voltage_Label[i], i, 0) for i in range(len(self.Voltage_Label))]
```

Answer (score 2):

also, you can try

```
font = QtGui.QFont("Times", 8, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
[label.setFont(font) for label in self.Voltage_Label]
```

if you are creating a font object every time you iterate over an item of `self.Voltage_Label` it will cost you some memory. so, therefore, you can share the same one with all the labels. whenever memory matters you can use this technique. but if you want to change the font on all `label` objects it won't change the font in other `QLabel` objects.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.